# Getting started with Robotium. EditText not found

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I just getting started with Robotium, writing my first test and I'm getting this weird error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 2131165500 EditTexts are not found!
```

This is my my test case

```
public class TestRegistrationActivity extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<RegistrationActivity>{

    private Solo solo;

    public TestRegistrationActivity() {
        super(RegistrationActivity.class);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }


    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public void testSomeStuff(){
        for (View v : solo.getCurrentViews()) {
            Log.d(v.getClass().getSimpleName()+": "+v.getId());             
        }

        solo.getEditText(R.id.txtCountryCode);
    }
}
```

And this is the log:

```
03-13 17:06:18.318: D/DEBUG(7907): EditText: 2131165500  
03-13 17:06:18.322: D/DEBUG(7907): PhoneEditText: 2131165501
```

As you can see:

1. The `solo.getCurrentViews()` does indeed recognize that the view with id `2131165500` exists.
2. The `solo.getEditText(R.id.txtCountryCode)` line always fails.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

The problem was that I thought `solo.getEditText(int)` took a `View` id as parameter. Instead it took the view's index.