# Robotium EditText no working

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, robotium

In Robotium i have a problem with `EditText`. I've searched everywhere but coudnt find solution for this.Only the issue is with `EditText` and for `ImageButton` i am using `View` its working fine. My code :

```
solo.enterText((EditText) solo.getView(R.id.etDetails),"13");
```

**LogCast**

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: View with id: '2131493017', resource name: '' is not found!

Comment: please show your logcast

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392654/getting-started-with-robotium-edittext-not-found) could help you

Comment: I had already tried that....but i t didnt worked.

Comment: Can you give me the sample code of that link,i might be wrong

Comment: Use `solo.getEditText(int)`

Comment: int abc = R.id.etDetails;solo.enterText((EditText) solo.getEditText(abc),"Hello");.....like this??

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText details = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.etDetails);
solo.enterText(details, "abc");
```

After a lot of Trial and Error, what eventually worked for me was the above code to edit the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

```
  EditText ETdetails= (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.etDetails);
  solo.clearEditText(ETdetails); // Clears contents if any
  solo.enterText(0, writeyourtexthere);
```

If you use morethan 1 edittext boxes , You have to inc at line number 3 first parameter value

I think, it will works fine.